# Integrating WSO2 Identity server with Liferay - Single Log Out issues

Tags: wso2, liferay, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to integrate WSO2 IS with Liferay as service provider, but I haven't been successful so far. Some modifications were made to the code, as per three JIRA issues raised and patches contributed by Benjamin Schmeling on WSO2 oxygen tank:
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2856

The SAML settings on WSO2 IS are as follows:

```
Assertion Consumer URL: liferayserver:8080/c/portal/saml/acs
NameID Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
Use fully Qualified username on NameID
Enable Response Signing
Enable Assertion Signing
Enable Single logout
    -> ConsumerURL: liferayserver:8080/c/portal/saml/slo_redirect
Enable attribute profile
```

Yet Liferay returns the following exception:

```
Liferay returns the following exception: 
[code]23:00:50,071 ERROR [http-thread-pool-8080(4)][BaseSamlStrutsAction:45] com.liferay.saml.UnsupportedBindingException
com.liferay.saml.UnsupportedBindingException
at com.liferay.saml.profile.SingleLogoutProfileImpl.processSingleLogout(SingleLogoutProfileImpl.java:216)
at com.liferay.saml.profile.SingleLogoutProfileUtil.processSingleLogout(SingleLogoutProfileUtil.java:54)
at com.liferay.saml.hook.action.SingleLogoutAction.doExecute(SingleLogoutAction.java:39)
at com.liferay.saml.hook.action.BaseSamlStrutsAction.execute(BaseSamlStrutsAction.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.BaseStrutsAction.execute(BaseStrutsAction.java:39)
```

I also tried changing the single log-out endpoint to liferayserver:8080/c/portal/saml/slo to no avail. In both cases the session is closed on the Identity Server (WSO2), but not on the service provider (Liferay).

Any ideas of what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are two additional modifications that are needed in order to make the Single log-out work. I'll leave these here in case they help someone else until these patches are integrated into their respective products. Special thanks to **Benjamin Schmeling**.

> For SAML-based SLO you should use the **/c/portal/saml/slo_redirect**
>   endpoint, however, Liferay is not able to handle post requests (at
>   least in the newest version of the SAML portlet). You have to **adapt
>   the Liferay SAML portlet** as follows:
>
> In **SingleLogoutProfileImpl.processSingleLogout(HttpServletRequest
>   request, HttpServletesponse response)** add a new else if branch:
>
> ```
>  else if(requestPath.endsWith("/slo_redirect") &&
>          method.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethods.POST)){
>          samlBinding = getSamlBinding(
>          SAMLConstants.SAML2_POST_BINDING_URI); }
> ```
>
> Furthermore, in
>   SingleLogoutProfileImpl.sendSpLogoutRequest(HttpServletRequest
>   request, HttpServletResponse response) after logoutRequest.setVersion
>   add the SessionIndex required by Wso2 by calling:
>   addSessionIndex(logoutRequest, samlSpSession.getSessionIndex());